# Per client profiles in Citrix

Tags: citrix, environment-variables, profile

I want to associate each Citrix client machine with a certain application specific profile (no windows profile or something similar). I have the following ideas to do this, but maybe there is a better way I am not aware of.

a) The client reads the environment variable "ClientName" and asks the server for the matching profile.

b) The client desktop could have several links to the application with a profile parameter. The user would then click one the link with the required profile. Several links would be needed since all clients use the exact same configuration.

c) Setting an environment variable per client in the citrix environment.

Any other / better idea?

Comment: Can you clarify your terminology - are you talking about Windows Roaming Profiles, or UPM or something else entirely? Do you mean Client as in "The device they're accessing Citrix from" or something else? I think we need to know more about what end result you're aiming for before we can help you

Comment: Also would like to have you clarify. Are you running a true VDI or a published desktop? Or are you just publishing applications out to them as they logon to a fat client?

Comment: @Dan I tried to clarify my question.

Comment: @Split71 I'm not sure whether it is a true VDI or a published desktop (it is not an environment in my company ...).

Comment: @deamon Are you the administrator of this setup? How do you expect to develop something for it if you don't even know what technology they're using? Is it XenApp, or XenDesktop?

Comment: @Dan That's what i was asking about before...published vs. true VDI

Answer (score 1):

See the section "Some More Advice" in my article [User Profile Design: A Primer](http://helgeklein.com/blog/2009/01/user-profile-design-a-primer/).

Essentially you create a system variable on each computer and use that variable in the profile path.